# Package Explorer-style package view in plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm writing a plugin with a custom editor, custom nature, builder etc.  I have a hierarchy of program files that function similarly to Java packages, and I would like the directories to be viewed in the same way that the JDT's Package Explorer shows them -- flat.  It seems I need to define a Navigator Content Extension that would detect the root folder and then generate children for all the packages.  I'm afraid that the individual folders would ALSO be shown, unless there's a way to suppress the default "children" methods.  Is there a good way to do this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@greg-449 had the bare basics, but here are some more details.
You basically have to re-implement everything.  The Project Explorer (common explorer) defines the Flat/Hierarchical preference, but does not implement it.  It is implemented only in internal JDT UI classes such as 
    `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorContentProvider`
and
    `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorLabelProvider`

The `navigatorContent` extension should be defined with an override of `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent`.  The context provider class should implement `IPipelinedTreeContentProvider2` and then if it detects a root folder (below which you want a flat view), it needs to change the "suggested" children to instead be an array of newly created objects, one for each package.  JDT uses `IPackageFragment`.  My solution uses a different interface with the same name.  The custom content provider class needs to handle this new interface/class too.

```
@Override
public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
  if (parentElement instanceof IPackageFragment) {
    Collection<IResource> files = new ArrayList<IResource>();
    ((IPackageFragment)parentElement).getElements(files);
    return files.toArray();
  } else if (isRootFolder(parentElement)) {
    Collection<IPackageFragment> packs = new ArrayList<IPackageFragment>();
    new FolderPackageFragment(EMPTY_NAME,(IFolder)parentElement).getSubpackages(packs);
    return packs.toArray();
  }
  return EMPTY_ARRAY;
}

@Override
public void getPipelinedChildren(Object aParent, Set theCurrentChildren) {
  Object[] children = getChildren(aParent);  
  // we only return EMPTY_ARRAY when we can't compute anything -- defer to current
  if (children == EMPTY_ARRAY) return;

  // now go to some effort to not get rid of everything and start from scratch.
  HashSet<Object> newSet = new HashSet<Object>();
  for (Object o : children) {
    newSet.add(o);
  }
  theCurrentChildren.retainAll(newSet);
  theCurrentChildren.addAll(newSet);
}
```

Then in order to get nice icons and package names, you need to write a custom `LabelProvider` also which handles folders and `IPackageFragment` objects and produces the right text and icons.  If you want problem icons to show up on the package icons, you have to manually request the `ProblemsMarkerDecorator` on your package icons, because the standard navigator won't recognize your "package fragment" objects otherwise.

```
  result = problemDecorator.decorateImage(result, pack.getBaseObject());
```

Here `getBaseObject` returns the underlying container under the package fragment `pack`.
Fortunately, the other decorators (such as GIT icons) will show up without you having to do anything, as long as your IPackageFragment objects can be adapted to `IContainer` objects.

If you forget to extend `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer` your extension will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code the `Package Explorer` does not use common navigator so I am not sure if you can duplicate it.

The `Project Explorer` which also does flat / hierarchical view is done with the common navigator so you should be able to reproduce what it does. It uses `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer` `viewContextBinding` and `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent/navigatorContext` `triggerPoints` and `possibleChildren`

Comment: Could you give me more details?  I looked at the Plug-In Registry for org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources and found the extension points uses you mention, but they don't seem to have anything to do with Flat/Hierarchical views (but rather for working sets).  I found that Project Explorer has a flat/hierarchical preference setting, which doesn't seem to have any effect.  Is it possible that this preference is there as an option for extensions, but that ProjectExplorer doesn't actually use it?

Comment: What sort of Project do you have for which the option works?  Java or plain?  If it works with a vanilla project (no Java Project Nature) then that's what I need!

Comment: The option is `Package Presentation > Flat / Hierarchical`. It only applies to Java packages.

Comment: What's a Java package? You mean it only applies to "src" folders in Java projects?  Am I right to assume that the option only works for you if the project has Java Nature?